# How to display last N number of records received with webservice using client side java script?

Tags: javascript, web-services, datatables, client-side-scripting

I'm working on the page and using existing Stored Procedure that is used on different screen.

I have a code that displays the entire result from stored procedure.
I need to show only last 40 records from the entire list of records retrieved.

Here is the fragment of a code I use:

```
......

myself.get_Service().SearchRecords(myID, '', '', function (result) {
    myself.get_Service().GetRecords(result, function (result) {
        RecordNotes = new Array();
        for (var ctr = 0; ctr < result.length; ctr++) {
            var record = result[ctr];
            RecordsNotes[RecordNotes.length] = new Array(record.CreatedDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), record.CreatedBy, record.CategoryName == null ? '' : record.CategoryName, record.Note);
        }
        $('#tblRecordNotes').dataTable().fnClearTable();
        $('#tblRecordNotes').dataTable().fnAddData(RecordNotes);
    });
    $("#txt_RecordNote").val("")
    $("#ddlCategories").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
}); 
......
```

How can I show only the last 40 records from the `result` object?

Answer (score 1):

If result has more than 40 records, you can [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the result like:

```
 result.slice(-40);
```

Comment: I modified the code with your change, but I still have result with the original number of records

Comment: why not to select last 40 rows from procedure ?

Comment: That procedure is used for other logic where there is no need to display only 40 rows